# Azure Blob Storage StartCopyFromUriAsync() Causes Zero Byte Files to be Copied

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services, blobstorage

I am copying some files from Azure Media Services to Azure blob storage and a lot of files get copied successfully but periodically some files get copied over and have a zero byte file size. I'm not sure why this would happen for some files and not others? They are all being copied over via URL from Azure Media Services.

```cs
var blob = container.GetBlobClient(fileName);
var operation = blob.StartCopyFromUriAsync(new Uri(url));
var fileSize = await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync(
    DelayStrategy.CreateExponentialDelayStrategy(
        initialDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), maxDelay: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)),
    CancellationToken.None);

// fileSize == 0 sometimes!
```

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Media Services to Azure Blob Storage and a lot of files get copied successfully, but periodically some files get copied over and have a zero-byte file size.

According to this **[MS-Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-copy-async-dotnet#copy-a-blob-from-a-source-within-azure)**, the problem with the **`StartCopyFromUriAsync`** method when copying zero-byte files from Azure Media Services to Azure Blob Storage is due to:

- If the **`copy operation`** is aborted before it completes. When you abort a copy operation, the destination blob will have a zero length.
- The copy operation is not guaranteed to start immediately or complete within a specified time frame and is performed on a best-effort basis.

You can use the code below to copy operation fails and the destination blob has a zero length. If the copy operation succeeds, it prints a message to the console with the size of the destination blob using .net.

**Code:**

```cs
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace CopyBlobExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "xxxxx";
            string containerName = "";
            string fileName = "234-ccc23";
            string url = "<your-source-url>";

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

            // Start the copy operation
            var operation = await blobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(new Uri(url));

            // Wait for the copy operation to complete
            var fileSize = await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync(
                DelayStrategy.CreateExponentialDelayStrategy(
                    initialDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), maxDelay: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)),
                CancellationToken.None);

            if (fileSize == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Copy operation failed. Destination blob has zero length.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Copy operation succeeded. Destination blob size: " + fileSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Copy operation succeeded. Destination blob size: Status: 200, Value: 157030359
```

[image: Screenshot of successful copy operation]

Also, You can refer this [Azure data movement Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library#copy-a-file-from-url-to-a-blob) to Copy a file from URL to a blob.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. I've added a retry mechanism if it detects zero byte files, it will retry up to three times.